# Create JSON using for loop, Express.js

Tags: json, express, for-loop

I'm newbie to express.js. I want to create a JSON using for loop. But the code returns object object. I don't know why. But for a single JSON, it returns as a JSON value. In this code, I have added a function to retrieve my JSON values from mongoDB. Please help me to complete this.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Followups.find({}).then(followupData => {
        Staffs.find({}).then(staffData => {
            Institutions.find({}).then(institutionData => {
                var fcount = Object.keys(followupData).length;
                var scount = Object.keys(staffData).length;
                var icount = Object.keys(institutionData).length;

                console.log(icount);

                var jsonData = '';

                function getStaffData(id) {
                    return staffData.filter(
                      function(staffData) {
                        return staffData._id == id;
                      }
                    );
                }

                function getInstitutionData(id) {
                    return institutionData.filter(
                      function(institutionData) {
                        return institutionData._id == id;
                      }
                    );
                }

                for (i=0; i<fcount; i++)
                {
                    fstaffid = followupData[i].staffid;
                    fschoolid = followupData[i].schoolid;
                    staffDetails = getStaffData(fstaffid);
                    institutionDetails = getInstitutionData(fschoolid);

                    jsonData += {
                        staffname : staffDetails[0].achternaam + ' ' + staffDetails[0].voornaam + ' ' + staffDetails[0].tv,
                        staffplace : staffDetails[0].plaats,
                        staffphone : staffDetails[0].telefoon,
                        schoolname : institutionDetails[0].instellingsnaam,
                        schoolplace : institutionDetails[0].plaatsnaam,
                        schoolphone : institutionDetails[0].telefoonnummer,
                        notes : followupData[i].notes,
                        date : followupData[i].date,
                        created_at : followupData[i].created_at,
                        status : followupData[i].seen
                    }

                }
                console.log(jsonData);

            res.render('followup', {followupData:followupData, jsonData: jsonData});
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use JSON.`stringify(jsonData)` to get the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by using concat

```
jsonData = jsonData.concat({
    followupid : followupData[i]._id,
    schoolid : followupData[i].schoolid,
    staffid : followupData[i].staffid,
    staffname : staffDetails[0].achternaam + ' ' + staffDetails[0].voornaam + ' ' + staffDetails[0].tv,
    staffplace : staffDetails[0].plaats,
    staffphone : staffDetails[0].telefoon,
    schoolname : institutionDetails[0].instellingsnaam,
    schoolplace : institutionDetails[0].plaatsnaam,
    schoolphone : institutionDetails[0].telefoonnummer,
    notes : followupData[i].notes,
    date : followupData[i].date,
    created_at : followupData[i].created_at,
    status : followupData[i].seen
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display the data of `jsonData` like:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
```

`object object` means **jsonData** is a JSON object, you cannot display a JSON object directly. You must `stringify` it before doing this.

You may be able to find more about the issue after using JSON.stringify